# paypal v2 curl api invalid_client

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

The question is about paypal API v2 and curl request, I'm getting `"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"`

(tested with cCurl and PHP, both same invalid_client error)

I'm using the documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2#orders_get
and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/___orderID___ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic __id__:__secret__"
```

I'm still in sandbox phase.

I have the feeling I miss a step or something but unable to figure out what...

I went to https://developer.paypal.com/ in the section My apps & credentials
were there is SANDBOX API CREDENTIALS with Client ID and Secret
Secret is enabled and tried to create a new one....

Is someone knows what to do at this point ?

Comment: Have you verified that your credentials are being passed correctly in your request?

Comment: This example shows that you need to base64 encode your credentials. Are you doing that? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/authorize-transaction/

Comment: So does this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/permissions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/permissions/) and [this example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/authorize-transaction/) of using basic authorization say that you need to base64 encode your id and secret. If you want to do this on the command line with curl:

```sh
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/___orderID___ \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n __id__:__secret__ | base64)"
```